# how to extract missing datetime interval in python

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I have a date dataframe where date contains 15 min of interval. I want to find the missing datetime interval. id should be copied from previous line but value should be nan
'''

```html
 date value id
   2021-12-02 07:00:00  12456677    693214
   2021-01-02 07:30:00  12456677  693214
   2021-01-02 07:45:00  12456677  693214
   2021-01-02 08:00:00  12456677 693214
   2021-01-02 08:15:00  12456665  693215
   2021-01-02 08:45:00  12456665  693215
   2021-01-03 09:00:00  12456666 693217
   2021-01-03 10:30:00  12456666   693217
```

expacted output is

```html
date value id
   
   2021-01-02 08:30:00  NAN  693215
   2021-01-02 09:15:00 NAN    693217
   2021-01-03 09:30:00 NAN    693217
   2021-01-03 09:45:00 NAN    693217
   2021-01-03 10:00:00  NAN   693217
```

I am trying

```html
df['Datetime'] = pd.to_datetime(df['date'])
df[ df['Datetime'].diff() > pd.Timedelta('15min') ]
```

but it is just giving a time after which date is missing. not the missing date and time.it showed me this output

```html
date value id

   2021-01-02 08:15:00  12456665  693215
   2021-01-03 09:00:00  12456666 693217
   2021-01-03 10:30:00  12456666   693217
```

can some one please guide me how can I extract missing date and time?
Thanks in advance

Comment: kindly post your expected output

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [`Series.asfreq`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.asfreq.html) per groups for get missing intervals:

```
#create DatetimeIndex
df['date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['date'])
df = df.set_index('date')

#add 15 Minutes index per days and per id
df1 = (df.groupby([pd.Grouper(freq='D'), 'id'])['value']
         .apply(lambda x: x.asfreq('15min'))
         .reset_index(level=0, drop=True)
         .reset_index())
print (df1)
        id                date       value
0   693214 2021-01-02 07:30:00  12456677.0
1   693214 2021-01-02 07:45:00  12456677.0
2   693214 2021-01-02 08:00:00  12456677.0
3   693215 2021-01-02 08:15:00  12456665.0
4   693215 2021-01-02 08:30:00         NaN
5   693215 2021-01-02 08:45:00  12456665.0
6   693217 2021-01-03 09:00:00  12456666.0
7   693217 2021-01-03 09:15:00         NaN
8   693217 2021-01-03 09:30:00         NaN
9   693217 2021-01-03 09:45:00         NaN
10  693217 2021-01-03 10:00:00         NaN
11  693217 2021-01-03 10:15:00         NaN
12  693217 2021-01-03 10:30:00  12456666.0
13  693214 2021-12-02 07:00:00  12456677.0
```

Test missing values in [`boolean indexing`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html#boolean-indexing):

```
df2 = df1[df1['value'].isna()]
print (df2)
        id                date  value
4   693215 2021-01-02 08:30:00    NaN
7   693217 2021-01-03 09:15:00    NaN
8   693217 2021-01-03 09:30:00    NaN
9   693217 2021-01-03 09:45:00    NaN
10  693217 2021-01-03 10:00:00    NaN
11  693217 2021-01-03 10:15:00    NaN
```

Comment: when I am writing this dataframe into csv it adds id and date but there is no value inside. I meann it is not showing NaN

Comment: @Katja - it is expected, pandas by default replace NaN to no value in to_csv. Then read_csv convert no value like NaN.